# Disable windows auth, but access a resource in the site collection

Tags: 2010, client-object-model, windows-authentication

I have a sitecol with anonymous access. I have a console code that uses client-object-model to query from a particular list in that site collection. This was working fine. But recently I had to disable windows integrated authentication on that webapplication. After that, the console code is not able retrieve data from the list (gets 401).

Question is, is there a way to keep the windows integrated auth disabled and some how allow access to query for that one list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, when you have the need to access content both as Anonymous/Forms and Windows, you usually have to extend the web application to a new port\hostheader combination and enable Windows Authentication on that.  Both web applications still point to the same data so there are no synchronization issues.

Here is a [short explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648385.aspx) of the approach